# DATABASE ERROR android.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Wall"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

the code snippent in which i am getting error is

```
String table = "WONDERS";
String column = "iamge";
String name = "name";
String query = "UPDATE " + table
    + " SET " + column + "=" + sle 
    + " WHERE " + name + link_global;


Cursor cu = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
cu.moveToFirst();
cu.close();
showList();
```

please help .

Comment: What is `link_global`?

Comment: link_global is a string variable containing the name for which i want to update.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be `name + "=" + link_global` in the last part of the String query.

Hence,

```
String query = "UPDATE " + table
    + " SET " + column + "=" + sle 
    + " WHERE " + name + "=" + link_global;
```

If link_global is a string, then you will have to use the quote marks, e.g.

`name + "='" + link_global + "'";`

Comment: Thanks, But I changed it to name + "=" + link_global but it didn't work.

Comment: If link_global is a string! then you will have to use the quote marks, e.g. name + "='" + link_global + "'";

Comment: no the link_global is a variable and the error I am getting now is 
`no such coulmn:taj,while compiling : UPDATE WONDERS SET iamge=taj WHERE name=Pyramid`
I don't understand why it is considering taj as a column instead of iamge ?

Comment: @user2665595 Because your missing quotes around the values that are strings

Answer (score 0):

Fix query to :

```
String query = "UPDATE " + table
+ " SET " + column + "=" + sle 
+ " WHERE " + name + "=" + link_global;
```

To update record with raw sql query use:

```
sqlHandler.execSQL(query);
```